# Show that $f'(z)$ is imaginary for $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is complex differentiable for $z \in i \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to show the statement above to be true. More specifically:

> If we have real-valued function $f(z)$ with a derivative defined over imaginary $z$, then $f'(z)$ is imaginary for all imaginary $z$.

***Clarification: I mean a function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is complex differentiable for $z \in i \mathbb{R}$. (Thanks sranthrop)***

I feel like my explanation is overly complicated and was wondering if I could get some other insights?

Since $f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x, y) + iv(x,y)$ (with $u, v$ being real) is real-valued we know it must be of the form $f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x, y)$. Consider the definition of the complex derivative, and since $f'(z)$ is only defined for imaginary $z$, we will consider $ih$ instead of $h$:

$f'(z) = \lim_{ih \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+ih) - f(z)}{ih} = \lim_{ih \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x, y + h) - u(x,y)}{ih} = -i \lim_{ih \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x, y + h) - u(x,y)}{h}$.

The limit above is just the partial derivative of $u$ w.r.t $y$ so we have:

$f'(z) = -i u_y(x,y)$. Since $u$ is real valued, so is its partial derivative and so $-iu_y(x,y)$ is imaginary and thus $f'(z)$ is also imaginary.

Comment: Real valued function with imaginary derivtive?? i do not understand..

Comment: Yeah the question is for a real valued complex function. With a derivative defined over all imaginary points $z$. I need to show this derivative is imaginary at all imaginary $z$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the same thing Marios pointed out. You mean $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Do you mean a function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ that is complex differentiable only at $z\in i\mathbb R$?

Comment: @sranthrop Yes exactly! Sorry I can't articulate this well.